# Is there an attribute I can add to a class so it will be edited as code, not in the designer?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I've made a class which inherits from UserControl, but which I only want to use as a base for subclasses.  Is there a way I can stop VS2008 from trying to edit it in the designer, that won't stop the subclasses from being edited in the designer?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is.  I believe if you have multiple classes in a file, VS looks at the first one only, but I may be mistaken.  In any case, this should do the trick:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class SomeBaseClass : UserControl
{
 //...
}
```

Note that in versions of Visual Studio prior to 2017,  you must use the full name of the attribute as shown above.  If you try putting a using statement above it and simply trying "DesignerCategory" visual studio may not honor it.

Comment: The base class now opens as code, but the derived classes *also* do.  But if you add a dummy class above with that attribute, it works a charm!

Comment: Be careful, just using `[DesignerCategory("Code")]` doesn't seem to work (looks like a bug in Visual). You have to write fully qualified name `[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]`

Comment: Looks like the bug has been fixed: `[DesignerCategory("Code")]`, without the namespace, works in Visual Studio 2017.