# Is it possible to tell Visual Studio not to treat a source file as a "component"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, components

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there an attribute I can add to a class so it will be edited as code, not in the designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230146/is-there-an-attribute-i-can-add-to-a-class-so-it-will-be-edited-as-code-not-in)

Class with `System.ComponentModel.Component` on their inheritance path are automatically treated as "components" within Visual Studio (2008), triggering a different icon for the source file:

[image]

While the icon does not really matter, the changed double click behavior is really annoying: instead of opening the source code in the text editor, Visual Studio now shows a screen encouraging me to add components to my class by dragging them "from the Toolbox". I do not want to do that!

I am aware that I can right click the source file and choose "View Code", but whenever I forget to do this, I am stuck waiting for a dialog which is absolutely useless. Is there any way to disable the component behavior (preferably in the source code)?

Comment: If you're stuck waiting for the dialog, your computer is too slow for a developer machine :) The same thing happens if you choose to add a partial class file for a form or control. Although it's basically a separate code-only file, it will open a designer (and it's, if I remember correctly, not the one for the actual form). Annoying, but I tend to right-click->View Code anyway on files that don't have the plain code symbol.

Comment: Heh, it's now like it takes a lot of time to open the dialog, but more like it takes several clock cycles in my brain to figure out that something went wrong :)

Comment: Also, the project in question is *not* winforms, so I really find it unfair that VS is bugging me with its pesky designers.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Can't you use the `DesignerCategory` attribute to decorate your class ?

When decorating your class with this attribute like displayed below, the file should open in 'code view' when you double click it:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class MyComponent
{
}
```

Comment: Exactly! It truly is weird that you *have* to use the fully qualified name for this attribute, though :)

Comment: Future readers note carefully @JørnSchou-Rode 's comment. It does seem to be the case that this only works if you use the fully qualified name of the attribute.

Comment: Ironically, Visual Studio allows to set different attributes on different partial file describing the same class and acts accordingly, but the compiled considers this an error.

Comment: Finally in Visual Studio 2017 you can just use [DesignerCategory("Code")]

Answer (score 5):

As OregonGhost already mentioned in his comment this also happens if you make a partial class file from a form.

The problem is even more worse. If you take a look into your project file you can find entries for every file include like this:

```
<Compile Include="FormMain.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

So the solution should be to delete the line `<SubType>...</SubType>` cause it seems to be the root of all the problems. But if you delete this line, save the file, open it in Visual Studio, save it again and take a look again into, the line will reappear!

There seems to be only one hard-coded exception within Visual Studio and this is *.Designer.cs. So there is no solution to accomplish this problem.

Comment: Nearly ten years later this unfortunately still seems true. I can set a  DesignerAttribute on only one of the partial classes and as soon that I mistakenly press <ENTER> on one of the others the subtype Form reappears in the project file for this partial file.

Answer (score 0):

You could right-click the source file, choose "View Code", then click "Set as Default". It's a bit of a blunt instrument, but if you have more false components in your solution than real components, then you may find it convenient.