# Why has Visual Studio marked my class as a component?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, ide

[image: A class diagram]

I have copy pasted some classes into this project, some from other projects. At some point VS has marked `Class1` as a component (you can see from the icon shown in the screenshot above). `Class2` is OK. There's no difference in the **File Properties** and no interesting difference in the code between `Class1` and `Class2` (*except see **edit** below)

It doesn't stop the code from compiling or running. Is it in fact a problem at all? It *is* inconvenient in that the IDE tries to open the Design window if you double click the file.

How does this happen, and how to fix?

**Edit:** Actually, there are interesting differences in the code window. At least, there must be, since removing a large chunk of the code causes the Solution Explorer to revert the file to a *Class* file. Restore the chunk and the file goes back to being a *Component*. Currently... investigating.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure why it does this thing, but I know how to get rid of it. Before your class put:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
```

It should work.

Comment: You must have the entire qualifier present in the attribute (as it's stated above), even If you have a using statement for System.ComponentModel.

Answer (score 5):

For the "why" part of your question (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138684/is-it-possible-to-tell-visual-studio-not-to-treat-a-source-file-as-a-component) which appears to be a duplicate):

> Class with System.ComponentModel.Component on their inheritance path
>   are automatically treated as "components" within Visual Studio (2008), triggering a different icon for the source file: