# A partial class has multiple form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, partial-classes, csproj

When I write a winforms application, I tend to create an *Implementation.cs* file for each form.

Say I have *Form1.cs*, I'd create a new file called *Form1.Implementation.cs* starting with `partial class Form1`.

*Form1.cs* just contains all the event callback methods (what the designer has done), everything else goes to *Form1.Implementation.cs*. It helps me write more readable code.

---

I wanted *Form1.Implementation.cs* to be a "subfile" just like *Form1.Designer.cs* is, so I edited *.csproj* file.

```
<Compile Include="Form1.Implementation.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

After reload, however, *Visual Studio* automatically adds `<SubType>Form</SubType>` right after `DependentUpon` element. Doubleclicking *Form1.Implementation.cs* doesn't show code but a designer with another initial empty form.

It's like

> "class *Form1*, which ISA *Form*, is(?) multiple forms."

I tried [adding `DesignerCategory` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139078/1986241) to class *Form1*, but it affects *Form1.cs*, as well.

Well, hitting 'Shift-F7' or 'Ctrl-Shift-0' is not a big deal.
I wonder if...

1. it's a glitch of *Visual Studio*,
2. the secondary(?) form really exists somehow,
3. it's going to blow up my winforms project someday

Comment: You should look into moving towards a more "architected" approach to your code. Perhaps MVP would suit.. where your Form merely becomes a dumb view and the actual code sits inside Presenters.

Comment: The attribute is for the `Form1` _type_, not for one of its _source files_. In fact, partial classes only exist in code and are merged during compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way of achieving what you tried is by adding `<DependentUpon>`, which you already know. Now Visual Studio automatically adds the `<SubType>Form</SubType>` for any class derived from [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Since your **Form1.cs** probably contains the line `public partial class Form1 : Form`, this is where the SubType is coming from.

The other files - **Form1.Designer.cs** and **Form1.Implementation.cs** may contain only `partial class Form1`, but since partial class definitions across multiple files are still effectively one  class definition, Visual Studio detects that it still inherits [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I believe you may already know that, but just in case [here's the MSDN article about the partial keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wa80x488.aspx). Don't worry about there being multiple instances of [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in this scenario. Remember this still is just one class - `Form1`, no mater over how many files you spread it.

In the end, all code files containing classes *(even partial!)* inheriting [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or  [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx)) are automatically opened in the Designer. This behaviour is by design.

The solution here is simple - either make a code file defining a separate class not based on [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or just use F7 to view the code of that file in Solution Explorer, however annoying that may seem. It doesn't matter if that code file is `<DependentUpon>` anything or not. Only the inheritance of [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) matters.

The best solution though, in my opinion, would be to stick to what Visual Studio is giving you:

- Designer-generated code stays in **Form1.Designer.cs**
- Your code (what you put in **Implementation**), goes in **Form1.cs** *(hit F7 to view that code instead of going to the designer)*

This is an approach my team has been sticking to for a few years now. It provides a basic means of separation of Designer code and hand-coded actions. To better separate your code, use a design pattern such as MVP, as suggested by Simon Whitehead in the comments.